# How to pass (string) conditions as function arguments?

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

I would like to pass in 3 conditions to the function "check" to apply to str1, in this case the output should be [False, False, True]:

```
def check(conditions):
    str1 = '/'
    print(conditions)

check(conditions=[str1.find('//www.fao.org')!=-1, str1.find('//fao.org')!=-1, str1[0]=='/'])
```

However, before even calling the function it runs an error:

```
NameError: name 'str1' is not defined
```

Because this means that the conditions are executed even before the function check can be executed, how can I pass these conditions as arguments?

Comment: variable str1 is in the function scope in this case. Move it out to a global scope if you want.

Comment: If you want to define a function to be evaluated against str1, define it as... well, _a function_, so `check()` can pass `str1` to it.

Answer (score 7):

Pass a list of *functions* to call on `str1`:

```
def check(conditions):
    str1 = '/'
    for f in conditions:
        print(f(str1))

check(conditions=[lambda x: x.find('//www.fao.org') != -1, lambda x: x.find('//fao.org') != -1, lambda x: x[0] == '/'])
```